# Cinnamon Desktop Panel Launcher & Taskbar Problems

Tags: cinnamon

Something happened to my Cinnamon desktop. I no longer have the task bar or panel launcher functioning properly and now I have a group window instead.

If I add a Panel Launcher from 'Add Applets to Panel', I get a small panel next to the system tray with Firefox, a terminal and file manager icons. If I select 'add to panel' from the Main menu, no icons get added to that panel but they do seem to get added to group window. However, I can only see them if I reload Cinnamon. Programs not in the group window show up on the task bar with title when started but items in the group window sometimes enlarge with the title when activated, sometimes not. If I remove the group window and activate it again, it's empty.

I have re-installed Cinnamon (`apt install --re-install`, I did not try to remove Cinnamon) and have reset to default several times, but still have the same problems.

I have Cinnamon 4.2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04, seems like the problems started after an update that involved x11 but not sure,previous to that everything was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run the following to bring up the Panel Editor:

```
/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py panel
```

3. From the panel editor, add a new panel on the panel and select where you would like it to be positioned.

Hope that helps.